# Big-Oh Analysis of For Loop

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I have the following for loop:

```
sum = 0
for i = 1 to n do
    for j = 1 to i^3 do
        for k = 1 to j do
            sum++
```

What is the strategy to determine the complexity of this loop?

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with for loops, the strategy is as simple as stacking summations one on top of the other.

Each loop corresponds to a sum, thus the complexity of this function is:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i³}j
$$
The sums correspond to the first two loops, and the $j$ term accounts for the last one. We can now develop this expressions using the partial sum for arithmetic progressions.

Therefore, the number of operations being done (and thus the complexity of the algorithm) is a function of $n$ pertaining to $\mathcal{O}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i³}j)$.

Comment: I understand how you turned this into a sum. How does this help me determine big o?

Comment: The sum represents the number of operations occurring in the loop, which in turn is represented by $\mathcal{O}$ notation

Answer (score 1):

I was going to make this a comment but it grew too long.

Given that you already understand how to obtain the sum 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i^3} j $$
for the number of additions to `sum`, now you just have to compute the sum explicitly!

The inner sum is easy; use the well-known triangle number formula $\sum_{j=1}^k j = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ to get
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{i^3} j = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i^3(i^3+1)}{2}.$$

This remaining sum looks a little hairy, fortunately since all we want is the order we can avoid explicitly computing this by noting that this is equal to
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n i^6 + \mathcal{O}(i^3),$$
so we can ignore the cubic term.

Then [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) tells us that $\sum_{i=1}^n i^p$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $p+1$, hence
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n i^6 = \mathcal{O(n^7)},$$
which is the complexity of the entire routine.

Comment: Thanks, Josh. Why did you put the i^3 into Big O notation, but left i^6 alone?

Comment: For $i>1$ the higher-degree terms dominate the expression, hence to get the order of the runtime we only need consider the largest degree term in the sum. The smaller degree ones do not impact $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Thank you, I have one more question. I am trying to find the part on the Faulhaber's formula page that allows us to conclude that the sum is Big O of n^7. Can you please point that out to me?

Comment: In the second paragraph, beginning "The formula says...". The right hand side is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $p+1$.

Comment: @MortalMan The explicit expression for $p=6$ is actually given in the last equation in the Examples section.